# Understanding compass sprite generation for smart layout

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

So, after a few days of research, I'm forced to write this question:

What is the best way to work with compass sprites ?

Using layout horizontal or vertical seems to work fine for me. But I'm not able to work with smart layout. I always face the same problem: when zooming the page (in or out) at some points, I can see a bit of a sibling sprite on my sprite. Its get overlapped.

Seems the only way to make it work is adding some space through compass sprite's configuration, but this is not supported with smart layout.

So, what to do ?

Use always an horizontal or vertical layout ? What is the performance impact ?

I mean, the size of the generated images will be very large as the number of sprites grows. And on compass's documentation they said that this can cause performance issues...

But using smart layout its totally useless for me because of this overlapping issues.

What do you people do usually ?

Its ok to go with horizontal or vertical layouts all the time and have the generated file growing vertical or horizontally without being in an optimal way ?

Asking this cause we gonna move soon to mobile and perform is a key point.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limiting factor on the image size is total amount of pixels so if you put them in the row instead of square it should be ok. Also, if design allows, you can  add to each sprite border with the element border and background so it will look ok.

But be aware that sprites have much less sense with upcoming internet standards. For example [SPDY](http://dev.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-best-practices):

> Don't use CSS sprites with external stylesheets - Resources in
>   external stylesheets are obviously only discovered after the external
>   stylesheet has been downloaded, and only once the rule matches an
>   element. The advantage they provide of reducing HTTP requests is
>   unnecessary with SPDY due to its multiplexing. Therefore, CSS sprites
>   just make it slower.

Comment: I cannot output border on those sprites. Or do you mean to include transparent border or each png before compile so I force the "spacing" ? That seems a bit hacky.
Means also that I should not concern about the layout, ie: if I have a sprite with long width, I should use horizontal layout and the reverse ?  Aren't people out there using smart layout on compass ?
SPDY ? How long until we have that ? I really need to optimize our site, and I think this is a key point.
Can somebody throw light about compass & spriting ?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your answer, will have a deeper look to that protocol, but I need an answer more concrete for my particular problem. Any other suggestion ? Thanks again !

Comment: @avcajaraville it's just how it is with the smart layout. It's an old problem. Read issue: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/718 it has some suggestions and in depth discussion and some work on the solution https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/pull/1303

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers. I will not mark it as accepted, because it is not answering my question, I still want to know which approaches uses other people. I also know this issues, but just wanted to know how to address them. Thanks also for the SPDY, but anyway, I think it not against sprites techniques. I understand it will low the number of request as this are multiplexed, but anyway, the less you have, the less you request; so even when its an improvement, I think its valid also to keep on with sprites technique !

Comment: @avcajaraville i don't think that extremely wide or long images can cause problems. Like i said the dimension isn't limiting factor.If tile set image  `width * height < 2 megapixels` you should be ok with all supported formats including jpeg on all modern devices. If it's not then the icon quality can suffer due to downsampling + it will be slower.  Smart layout exist to plug holes for example when you have one wide and one long  tile + some small tiles this algorithm will help you to fill all the tile set square instead of leaving gaps.

Comment: Ok, seems pretty much the best answer I can get. So I think I will do the sprites on an vertical / horizontal layout. Cannot get rid of the overlapping on the smart layout and your explanation seems pretty valid for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @avcajaraville Arranging sprites horizontally can result in smaller file size - in comparison to the vertical way.